# Are numbers generated by rand() in matlab dependent?

Tags: matlab, math, random, random-seed

I have a question about rand() in MATLAB.

I want to know whether the numbers generated by rand() are dependent.

For example, I generate directly a 1*2 matrix N by rand().

Will N(1) influence the N(2)? If N(1) is 0.2, then N(2) will greater or less than 0.2 with higher probability?

Comment: In theory no, they are random. In practice, if you're asking, you won't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I generated a 01 sequence by randsrc() in MATLAB. The element of the sequence is either 0 or 1. This function will use rand() when generating random numbers  and it can specify the probability of occurrence of 1. Can I regard this sequence as a Bernoulli process?

Comment: [Just for fun](http://www.physics.wisc.edu/~lmaurer/projects/minirng/Dilbert0001.jpg)

Comment: @roov: Mad Physicist already answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

Absent special hardware, computers cannot really generate random numbers. They use algorithms to generate pseudorandom numbers these are called pseudorandom number generators ("PRNG").

In the case of matlab, it uses the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) as its [default](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) generator.
The linked Wikipedia entry sums up the strengths and weeknesses of the Mersenne Twister nicely.

Because of the way a PRNG works, subsequent outputs of a PRNG *are* dependent. Or as James Polk suggested, it is more accurate to say that subsequent values depend on the internal state, which changes in a deterministic way with every call.

If you re-seed a PRNG with the same value, it will produce the same sequence of numbers as before. See the example below in Python (which also uses the Mersenne Twister).

```
In [1]: import random                                                                                    

In [2]: random.seed('foobar')                                                                            

In [3]: [random.randint(0, 255) for j in range(15)]                                                      
Out[3]: [128, 127, 178, 80, 112, 31, 1, 234, 24, 206, 253, 213, 6, 215, 16]

In [4]: random.seed('foobar')                                                                            

In [5]: [random.randint(0, 255) for j in range(15)]                                                      
Out[5]: [128, 127, 178, 80, 112, 31, 1, 234, 24, 206, 253, 213, 6, 215, 16]
```

And *eventually* the sequence will repeat itself. This is called the "period" of the PRNG.

If this PRNG has just been started it can take a while before it produces output of a good randomness because of the large internal state. You'd have to run tests to see if that is the case in matlab. It could be that the matlab developers have dealt with this be generating and discarding a significant amount of random numbers when initializing the generator.

To test this, generate several 1 kiB blocks of random bytes using matlab.
Then use e.g [dieharder](https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) or [ent](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/) to check and compare the randomness of the subsequent blocks.

Comment: Is dieharder or ent to check whether the numbers of two blocks are dependent? I just want to know the numbers in one block are dependent or not.

Comment: @roov No, those programs test for randomness. The numbers are dependent.

Comment: "Dependent" can be more complicated than this. The outputs of a PRNG are dependent on the internal state, but at best only very weakly on each other.

Comment: The numbers are not dependent, in that one period of the Mersenne Twister produces each possible integer many, many times (the period is 2^19937 − 1, producing only 2^32 different integers). Consequently, knowing one value from the sequence, it is impossible to determine which one will be the next one. You need to know the full internal state for that.